# Зачем нужны параметры в функциях в javascript?

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю, зачем нужны параметры в функциях в js.
Вот есть два примера: первый с параметрами, а второй нет.

```
function summa(a,b) { // 1
    return(a+b);
}
alert(summa(12 , 5));

function summa() { // 2
    var a = +prompt("A?" , '');
    var b = +prompt("B?" , '');
    return(a+b);
}
alert(summa());
```

Какая польза от параметров???

Comment: Ну как минимум параметры можно будет взять откуда угодно, а не только из prompt

Comment: А если нужно запустить функцию с результатом выполнения первой, как вы это будете делать без параметров и не зная какие они получатся? В первом случае a и b могут быть любые, а во втором случаем только то что укажите..

Comment: Если нужно выполнить набор каких-то действий несколько раз, но с разными значениями данных, то не нужно каждый раз дублировать код, а просто передать через параметры новые значения.

Comment: @Haswell: `function A () { var a = B(); }` :-D

Comment: @Grundy, согласен, можно как результат вернувшийся от функции)

Answer (score 3):

Вы используете функцию `alert()` в своих примерах. То, что вы передаёте в её скобки и есть параметры. Так если от параметров нет пользы, то как вы выведете что то в `alert()`? Аналогично с другими функциями.

Кроме того, не все функции должны принимать параметры от пользователя.

Прведу пример, где вы найдете ответ на свой вопрос.

```
function increase(a) { // Возвращает переданное значение, увеличенное на 10
    return a + 10;
}

for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    alert( increase(i) );
}
```

В данном примере есть переменная `i`, которую пользователь не вводит сам при использовании программы. функция `increase` срабатывает 10 раз, но пользователь не вводит каждый раз новое значение.

Comment: если сделать параметр `a` глобальной переменной, то функция `increase` останется без параметров, а результат выполнения кода не изменится :-) если конечно заменить в цикле счетчик на `a` :)

Comment: Про ``alert()``  - отличное замечание!

Comment: @Grundy Чему будет равна та глобальная переменная?

Comment: @Эникейщик, `for (a = 0; a <= 10; a++) {` - от 0 до 10 :)

Comment: @Grundy Маткабоска, я всегда думал, что переменная цикла видна только в цикле %-)

Comment: @Эникейщик, только не в яваскрипте :-D https://jsfiddle.net/xbvr8ekL/

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете заранее откуда-то получить данные и передать их в функцию, не всё можно получить через `prompt`.